# Which URL schemata can actually be linked?

Tags: support, markdown, hyperlinks

While trying to link an IRC channel on a tag wiki, I had to realize that all four ways to create a link in SO's markdown failed. Trying a bit around, I noticed the link would render if I would change the schema from `irc` to `http`. It seems `https` and `ftp` are working as well. But what else does?

The [official documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#links) doesn't mention which schemata are actually supported. Here on meta, I can only find answers regarding [unsupported schemata](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182088/allow-links-to-rdar-urls). Am I missing something?

Comment: No. It isn't a *possible* duplicate. It *is* a duplicate :-/

Comment: That's the default text that is inserted when you vote to close.

Comment: Oh splendid. My first question on the SE network *ever* and I genuinely made a fool out of me.

Comment: You absolutely haven't. Don't worry about it – this is just Meta.